# How to verify contents are greyed out

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

The application for which I'm writing script (using selenium-webdrive with Ruby) is built in AJAX. In that, I want to check whether contents are greyed out-

  I clicked on button

  Then div is loaded but I can see contents are greyed out & following div in firebug -

```
<div id="bottomHalf" class="disabled" style="background-color: transparent;">
```

To check whether it's greyed out, I'm confused how to write code. Based on my knwoledge, I could only find element -

```
driver.find_element(:id, "bottomHalf")
```

But I don't know how to write code for checking class="disabled" so that I can verify that contents are really greyed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors instead of bare ID selection.

```
driver.find_element(:css, '#bottomHalf.disabled')
```

More info about available selection options is available [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/SearchContext.html#find_element-instance_method)

Answer (score 0):

You are in right direction mate...After finding an element you can retrieve the Attributes of that Element. In Ruby use the following method.

```
# get an attribute
class_name = element.attribute("class")
```

Here is an example in C# for retrieving attribute values after finding an element.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
IWebElement Element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("gbqfq"));
String Class_name = Element.GetAttribute("Class");
```

Check this URL for more Ruby Selenium specific Bindings
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings